# How to set up IBM work light server on my machine

Tags: apache, ibm-mobilefirst

Hello Folks,

We are recently working on IBM worklight and what we want to try is:

We have two machine, one we want to set as server and other one is for my developer to build the app.

Currently we have installed Apache Tomcat server on the machine which we want to make as server. We even have IBM Worklight installed on it. Now What I want to achieve is to deploy the app from other machine to this server. But I am not able to set up the things properly.

Things done so far:

- Installed Apache Tomcat server software on a machine (server)
- Installed IBM Installation Manager

I am not getting how will I set up the Worklight Server on this machine. Can anyone provide some information?

Comment: Did you try this [link](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc%2Fappcenter%2Ft_configuring_apache_tomcat.html) to configure the server? once you configure the server follow this [link](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc%2Fappcenter%2Ft_configuring_apache_tomcat.html) to deploy the WAR ( worklight console ) and  applications ( Wlapps and adapter files)

Comment: Thanks bluewings . But what i want to do is I want to install the IBM worklight on apache tomcat server so that I can deployee the apps from various other machines over here and keep my app running all the time

Comment: you cant deploy directly to external server. First build the WAR file and deploy that in server then deploy all the WLAPP and Adapters in worklight console

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly deploy from Worklight Studio (the Eclipse plug-in) to a remote Worklight Server.

The steps you need to take are:

1. Setup your application for a remote server, via the [Build Settings and Deploy Target](http://engtest01w.francelab.fr.ibm.com:9090/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_building_and_deploying_build_settings_deploy_target.dita) window
2. Build the app
3. Take the .wlapp/.adapter file and deploy it to the remote Worklight Server via it's Worklight Console

If you have done any server-related changes (authenticationConfig.xml, Java code, ...) you will need to first [deploy the project's .war](http://engtest01w.francelab.fr.ibm.com:9090/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/PLUGINS_ROOT/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/c_deploy_wl_project.html) file to the application server that hosts the remote Worklight Server, and then the .wlapp.

Comment: thanks idan . I will work on the steps suggested by you and let you know the outcome!

Comment: If my answer helped you resolve this issue, please mark as answered.